# log4j2 does not log in webapplication deployed on tomcat

Tags: maven, tomcat, web-applications, configuration, log4j2

I am upgrading the version of log4j for a web application running on Tomcat 8. I am upgrading from version 1.2.12 to the latest 2.11.1.

The application is using Maven. So I added the following dependencies to my application `pom.xml` (version is managed in parent pom):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

I removed the old configuration file `log4j.properties` and replaced it by a new `log4j2.xml` file in the folder `src/main/resources` (find below my log4j2 file content).

When I am running directly a `main` function, the logs are correctly written in console and in a file. However when I deploy the application on Tomcat, and run it, no log is written.

I checked my application WAR, and both libraries are present in `WEB-INF/lib` folder.
I also tested by adding exclusions to log4j-1** to external libraries that have dependency on it, but nothing changed...

Did someone already had the same issue, and how did you correct it?

Regards,
Matthieu

PS: content of my log4j2.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status=WARN strict="true">
    <Properties>
        <Property name="pattern">%d [%t] (%F:%L) %x %-5p [%c{1}] %m%n</Property>
        <Property name="filePath">C:/temp/logs/my_app/my_app.log</Property>
    </Properties>

    <Appenders>
        <Appender type="Console" name="STDOUT">
            <Layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="${pattern}"/>
        </Appender>
        <Appender type="RollingFile" name="FILE" fileName="${filePath}" filePattern="${filePath}.%i">
            <Layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="${pattern}"/>
            <Policies>
                <SizeBasedTriggeringPolicy size="500KB"/>
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy max="1"/>
        </Appender>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>
        <Logger name="my.package.debug" level="DEBUG" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
        </Logger>
        <Root level="WARN">
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="FILE"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "does not log in webapplication". In which folder do you expect the logs to be? Did you find the logs - in which folder are they or does the application in tomcat not create any log files or more specifically not create any "my_app.log" file?

Comment: @NiklasP The application in tomcat does not create the "my_app.log" file, that was I meant when I said "does not log in webapplication".

Comment: Can you also answer my other questions? In which folder do you expect the logs to be? Did the webapplication create the logs in a different folder or no logs at all - have you analyzed that?

Comment: @NiklasP Sorry, I expected the log to be created in this folder `C:/temp/logs/my_app/`, and there are no logs at all in any places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found my issue, it was due to another library (infinispan-embeded) which was redefining Log4j classes, such as LogManager. I was loading thoses classes instead of those in log4j libraries, and they was in older version than what I wanted.

I just replaced the library, and logs are correctly written in file.